# Google app engine and numpy don't work toghether on local development server

Tags: python, google-app-engine, numpy, osx-mavericks

I am trying to work with numpy and google app engine locally on the development server on mac osx 10.9.

However I dont cannot run them togehter. 
So I have two questions:
- Why can I not install numpy 1.6.1?
- Why can I import numpy 1.8.1 in normal python but not in combination with GAE?

Below are the 2 scenarios that fail:

Running app locally:
1]
    Trying to use numpy 1.8.0

```
app.yaml:
libraries:
- name: numpy
  version: latest

Numpy version:
$ pip freeze
numpy==1.8.0

in main.py:
import numpy as np
    Error Message:
    ImportError: No module named future_builtins

however: 
$ python
>>> import numpy as np
>>>
Importing it without google app engine works.
```

2]
    Trying to install numpy 1.6.1 on my mac
    $ pip install numpy==1.6.1

```
clang: error: invalid argument '-faltivec' only allowed with 'ppc/ppc64'
....
failed with exit status 1
```

Settings:
    Python path for GAE launcher:
    /usr/local/bin/python

```
Python version:
Python 2.7.6

OS:
MAC OS X 10.9

$ brew --version
0.9.5

$ pip --version
pip 1.4.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)
```

Answer (score 2):

The error with 1.8 is due to this bug, marked as fixed but not yet in a released SDK: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8367

In the meantime, you can add '`future_builtins`' to the end of the list in google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/sandbox.py, line 814. Note that the comment along with 'Fixed' suggests this *won't* be in release 1.8.9, so you'll have to re-apply the fix when you upgrade to that version.

(Fwiw, I get the same error trying to install 1.6.1)

Comment: Thanks for that. I added patch, but I still get the same error. Do I need to rebuilt the bundle? If yes, do you know how to do that? Thanks

Comment: Now I got it to work. I added the line in sandbox.py instead of applying the patch.